# Regular expression character class with parenthesis with grep command

Tags: regex, grep

Regular expression with grep command. For example let say i have file called regular.txt which contain date like below:

```
$ cat regular.txt
    july
    jul
    Fourth
    4th
    4
```

So i am trying match all these text from the input file,using below process method:

Method 1: Match only Fourth|4th|4

```
   $egrep '(Fourth|4th|4)` regular.txt
```

## output method 1:

```
    Fourth
    4th
    4
```

Method 2: Match only Fourth|4th|4 using optional parenthesis

```
  $ egrep '(Fourth|4(th)?)` regular.txt
```

## output method 2:

```
    Fourth
    4th
    4
```

Method 3: Match entire file july, jul, Fourth, 4th, 4. i am using command like below:

```
$ egrep 'july? (Fourth|4(th)?)` regular.txt
```

## output method 3: Nothing will be match here. how to do this ?

could you please help me on this ?

Thanks,

Comment: You need July or 4th or Fourth or July followed by fourth?

Comment: Well, `Fourth|4(th)?|july?`?

Comment: Hi Witor, You are right.

Comment: Hi SMA, I needed output Jully followed by fourth.

Comment: There is no "character class" here.  A regex character class is a construct for matching a single character out of a set.

Answer (score 2):

Your `july? (Fourth|4(th)?)` regex matches a *sequence* of patterns, `jul` followed with an optional `y`, then a space, and then 2 alternatives: `Fourth` or `4` optionally followed with `th` substring.

If you plan to match `jul` or `july` as a 3rd alternative, add it to the grouping construct:

```
'Fourth|4(th)?|july?'
              ^   ^^
```